# How does being cloaked affect minimap visibility?

Tags: nuclear-dawn

Cloaked stealths are invisible to players (except the assault with his visor down, but that's not the point), but do they appear on the minimap?  Does alignment affect it? E.g. can I see allied cloaked stealths on my minimap but not enemy ones? Do I see all of them? None of them?

How does being cloaked affect minimap visibility?

Answer (score 2):

You can see allied stealth on the minimap all the time but the opponents cloaked stealths only appear on the minimap if they get near a decloaking structure (command bunker, assembler, radar station).